Generic Webhook Trigger not trigger pipline in multibranch
Im using Generic Webhook Trigger to trigger multibranch pipeline in GitLab project with webhook.
I'm using a token in the pipeline.
in the gitlab webhook response I'm getting status 200 but no jobs triggered in jenkins pipeline.
here is the webhook response:
{"jobs":{"TEST/Domaine/test1/cicd":{"regexpFilterExpression":"$payload","triggered":false,"resolvedVariables":{"payload":"{"object_kind":"push","event_name":"push","before":"a11387a0299aa2ffec1f49c64f5486fb1a102628","after":"f8756635f23a1a78bd70f9a38b27a75782d0dfa7","ref":"refs/heads/testcicd","ref_protected":false,"checkout_sha":"f8756635f23a1a78bd70f9a38b27a75782d0dfa7","message":null,"user_id":86....
